# Remove document from collection using non-generic EQ-Query

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I´m trying to remove a document from my collection using the non-generic EQ-Query, but it does not remove anything. With the generic EQ-Query the document gets removed successfully.

Here´s the object I´m storing in MongoDB.

```
public class UserDto {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

And here´s the sample code how I remove the document from the collection.

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<UserDto>(typeof(UserDto).Name);

var single = collection.AsQueryable<UserDto>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == 46);

// using the generic version will remove the document.
//var result = collection.Remove(Query<UserDto>.EQ(p => p.Id, 46));

// using the non-generic version will not remove the document.
var result = collection.Remove(Query.EQ("Id", BsonValue.Create(46)));
```

Is there something wrong with the setup of my MongoQuery to remove the document?

I´m using MongoDB 2.6.1 and MongoDB Driver C# 1.9.1.221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't configured otherwise your `Id` field will be considered by the driver the Id of the document. Which means that the field in `MongoDB` would be "_id" and not "Id".

When you use the generic query the driver does the translation for you. The non-generic query should look like this:

```
var result = collection.Remove(Query.EQ("_id", 46));
```